# Avoid layout change animations in custom view, that's updated in the WindowManager

Tags: android, animation, view, android-windowmanager

I have a custom `RelativeLayout` and I even have set `setLayoutTransition(null);`. I add this custom view to the WindowManager with `((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).updateViewLayout(this, layoutParams);`

I change views in the custom view AND I change the `LayoutParams` for the `WindowManager` and afterwards call `updateViewLayout`...

I think, the chang of the `LayoutParams` for the `WindowManager` is animated, but I'm not sure...

How can I disable ALL animations?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This one's a little annoying. Android animates all window changes, and they've made the flag to disable it private. You can disable window animations using `reflection`

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    String className = "android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams";
    try {
        Class layoutParamsClass = Class.forName(className);

        Field privateFlags = layoutParamsClass.getField("privateFlags");
        Field noAnim = layoutParamsClass.getField("PRIVATE_FLAG_NO_MOVE_ANIMATION");

        int privateFlagsValue = privateFlags.getInt(wp);
        int noAnimFlag = noAnim.getInt(wp);
        privateFlagsValue |= noAnimFlag;

        privateFlags.setInt(wp, privateFlagsValue);

        // Dynamically do stuff with this class
        // List constructors, fields, methods, etc.

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Logger.l.e(e.toString());
        // Class not found!
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.l.e(e.toString());
        // Unknown exception
    }
```

Now `wp` will not animate layout changes. Note you'll probably see flicker when you change the window size.  I haven't found a way to work around that yet.

Comment: That's what I'm doing currently. I just use `flag |= 0x00000040;` instead of the name and I don't call `Class.forName` but rather use the class directly. Thanks anyway, I'll mark your answer as correct

Comment: You've got to use `Reflection` as this is a `privateFlag`. You can't just apply it as a regular flag.

Comment: As I said, I do the same thing you say, just with the above mentioned differences. Of course, I use reflection as well. I just meant, that I already had solved the problem myself... Still your answer is correct and therefore I marked it as answer.

Comment:  gotcha. always use flag names instead of constants. You never know when a flag constant might change and you're stuck with a problem you can't debug.

Comment: actually, that was the reason why I used the number. I thought, this is more save than the name as I assume in this case the number won't change...

Comment: I only said it because I spent several hours debugging a reflections issue a few years ago where a flag value changed on another library. Generally the value is much more likely to change than the variable name. Variable names are deprecated. I'm overly cautious though. Happy coding!

Comment: I understand. Appreciate that hint. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @stewjacks, this solves also the question that I posted on SO one month ago, namely almost two years after you had posted your answer.. Here is my question, I copy the link in case someone else is trying to solve the same problem (or maybe has some suggestions):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44226196/android-view-resize-and-windowmanager-unwanted-transition-during-child-view-pla

Thanks!

Comment: I did this but still there is a glitch which is visible from naked eyes did any one got workaround for that..

Comment: This works but my device is getting turned off immediately when the app set this flag.

Comment: @sector11, one possible solution - to call `removeView` and `addView` instead of `updateViewLayout`