# Android View resize and WindowManager: unwanted transition during child view placement

Tags: android, viewgroup, android-transitions, android-windowmanager, onmeasure

I'm having some problems in avoiding an unwanted transition during child view placement in a custom `ViewGroup` after parent view resizing. This problem seems to be only present when using the `WindowManager` instead of the call to `setContentView()`. Here is a short example:

`MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APPS = 1;
    CustomViewGroup mCustomViewGroup;
    WindowManager mWindowManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, MY_PERMISSIONS_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APPS);
        }


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)) {


                } else {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APPS);
                }
            }
        }

        mCustomViewGroup =
                (CustomViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams floatingViewLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
        floatingViewLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT;
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mWindowManager.addView(mCustomViewGroup,floatingViewLayoutParams);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APPS) {
            //Check if the permission is granted or not.
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Draw over other app permission not available. Closing the application",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                finish();
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

}
```

`CustomViewGroup`:

```
public class CustomViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    private boolean mIsTouchEventActive;

    public CustomViewGroup(Context context) {
        this(context,null,0);
    }

    public CustomViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context,attrs,0);
    }

    public CustomViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {

        mIsTouchEventActive = false;
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        // Add the fab view
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View fabView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fab_view,null,false);
        this.addView(fabView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldDelayChildPressedState() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {


        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mIsTouchEventActive = true;
                requestLayout();
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mIsTouchEventActive = false;
                requestLayout();
                return true;

        }
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {


        int maxHeight = 0;
        int maxWidth = 0;
        int childState = 0;

        final View child = getChildAt(0);
        if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {

            measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, child.getMeasuredWidth());
            maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, child.getMeasuredHeight());
            childState = combineMeasuredStates(childState, child.getMeasuredState());

        }

        maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, getSuggestedMinimumHeight());
        maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, getSuggestedMinimumWidth());
        if (mIsTouchEventActive == true) {

            final Display display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
            Point deviceDisplay = new Point();
            display.getSize(deviceDisplay);

            maxHeight = deviceDisplay.x;
            maxWidth = deviceDisplay.y;
        }


        setMeasuredDimension(resolveSizeAndState(maxWidth, widthMeasureSpec, childState),
                resolveSizeAndState(maxHeight, heightMeasureSpec, childState << MEASURED_HEIGHT_STATE_SHIFT));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

        final Rect fabChildRect = new Rect();
        final View child = getChildAt(0);
        if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {

            final int width = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            final int height = child.getMeasuredHeight();

            fabChildRect.left = 0;
            fabChildRect.right = width;
            fabChildRect.top = 0;
            fabChildRect.bottom = height;

            child.layout(fabChildRect.left, fabChildRect.top,
                    fabChildRect.right, fabChildRect.bottom);

        }
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packagename.CustomViewGroup
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_view_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
```

`fab_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The manifest file should contain the `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission and my dependency list in `build.gradle` is the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here is what I'm doing:

I have a custom view `CustomViewGroup` inheriting from `ViewGroup` which in my short example contains a `FloatingActionButton`, placed in the bottom-left corner of the parent view. The default sizes of `CustomViewGroup` are those of the contained `FloatingActionButton`: 264x264.

I've implemented the `onClick` and `onMeasure` methods in `CustomViewGroup` so that in case of an `ACTION_DOWN` event the size of `CustomViewGroup` is expanded to the whole display. In case of a `ACTION_UP` event the size returns to the default one. The position of the `FloatingActionButton` within the `CustomViewGroup` is always

```
fabChildRect.left = 0;
fabChildRect.right = width;
fabChildRect.top = 0;
fabChildRect.bottom = height;
```

where `width` and `height` are both equal to 264, therefore the button itself is placed in different positions when the parent view sizes change after a user touch.

My question is: how can be removed the animation during the action button placement in case of a user touch event? I mean the vertical motion of the button view. I have already tried with the `disableTransitionType` method with all the transition types but nothing changes. Same if I try to disable the transitions in the xml files. This transition is not present if the `CustomViewGroup` view is added to the main activity view by inflating it from the xml instead of using the `WindowManager`, for example with the following `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="packagename.MainActivity">

    <packagename.CustomViewGroup
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/custom_view_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Do you have any advice on how to solve my problem and maybe also an explanation for what I'm observing? As you can probably guess from my code I'm a beginner in Android programming so any advice in general also not strictly related to the topic of this thread is more than welcome!

Thank you.

UPDATE: I've found that using the `WindowManager` there is a call to

```
int relayoutResult = mWindowSession.relayout(
    mWindow, mSeq, params,
    (int) (mView.getMeasuredWidth() * appScale + 0.5f),
    (int) (mView.getMeasuredHeight() * appScale + 0.5f),
    viewVisibility, 
    insetsPending ? WindowManagerGlobal.RELAYOUT_INSETS_PENDING : 0,mWinFrame, 
    mPendingOverscanInsets, mPendingContentInsets, mPendingVisibleInsets,
    mPendingStableInsets, mPendingOutsets, mPendingConfiguration, mSurface);
```

within `ViewRootImpl` (line 5415) and the unwanted visible transition is performed during the execution of this method. If I inflate the `CustomViewGroup` from the xml in the main activity the above method is not called in case of a touch event and since in this condition also the transition is not visible I guess that I can consider the `relayout` method of the `mWindowSession` data member (type is `IWindowSession`) its responsible.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338359/avoid-layout-change-animations-in-custom-view-thats-updated-in-the-windowmanag?rq=1

It seems that I didn't search enough before posting my question...